# Remove leading zeros before decimal in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to remove the number to the left side of the decimal if that digit is less than 1.  Basically, I want to remove a zero if its there.

Meaning 0.25 would become .25 but 1.50 would remain 1.50

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mytabl').DataTable({
    "searching": true,
    "pageLength": 40,
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    drawCallback: () => {
      const table = $('#mytabl').DataTable();
      const tableData = table.rows({
        search: 'applied'
      }).data().toArray();
      const totals = tableData.reduce((total, rowData) => {
        total[0] += parseFloat(rowData[1]);
        total[1] += parseFloat(rowData[2]);
        return total;
      }, [0, 0]);
      $(table.column(1).footer()).text(totals[0]);
      $(table.column(2).footer()).text(totals[1]);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: number.replace(/^0+/, '')

Comment: Do this where you render it, as a string. You could use a simple regex, such as `/^0+/`

Comment: The first answer on the question linked is actually wrong for that question but right for this one i.e. they asked for `0.22` and you for `.22`

Comment: I hardly know the basics of JavaScript. So far up to this point its been trial and error and asking questions on here. How would I implement this for my particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex

```
^0+(?=\d*\.\d+)
```

- `^` - start of string
- `0+` - Match `0` one or more time
- `(?=\d*\.\d+)` - Match must be followed by digit zero or time and a decimal and one or more digits after it

```js
let nums = ["0.25","1.25","001.23",".23",'0.0']

nums.forEach(value=>{
  value = value.replace(/^0+(?=\d*\.\d+)/,'')
  console.log(value)
})
```

Comment: @NickT you can change value to this format before `$(table.column(1).footer()).text(totals[0]);` and then pass the values

Comment: I should be more clear. I don't really know JavaScript. I'm basically just using it for a tiny function of my website. Can you be more specific please.

Comment: Can anybody help with the specifics please?